# ZEO can't find its own files?

Tags: python, zodb

See the following (very simple) code:

```
import ZEO
address, stop = ZEO.server()
```

Keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\2025a\Documents\Code\Tamagemon\archive\origin\create.py", line 2, in <module>
    address, stop = ZEO.server()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ZEO\__init__.py", line 98, in server
    return forker.start_zeo_server(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ZEO\_forker.py", line 222, in start_zeo_server
    fd, tmpfile = tempfile.mkstemp(".conf", prefix='ZEO_forker',
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\tempfile.py", line 357, in mkstemp
    return _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags, output_type)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\tempfile.py", line 256, in _mkstemp_inner
    fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0o600)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\2025a\\Documents\\Code\\Tamagemon\\ZEO_forkerd7oivnso.conf'
'''

See the following (very simple) code:

'''
import ZEO
address, stop = ZEO.server()
'''

Keep getting this error:
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\2025a\Documents\Code\Tamagemon\archive\origin\create.py", line 2, in <module>
    address, stop = ZEO.server()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ZEO\__init__.py", line 98, in server
    return forker.start_zeo_server(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ZEO\_forker.py", line 222, in start_zeo_server
    fd, tmpfile = tempfile.mkstemp(".conf", prefix='ZEO_forker',
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\tempfile.py", line 357, in mkstemp
    return _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags, output_type)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\tempfile.py", line 256, in _mkstemp_inner
    fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0o600)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\2025a\\Documents\\Code\\Tamagemon\\ZEO_forkerd7oivnso.conf'
```